# Pass value between pages for state mantain

Tags: asp.net

how to Transfer values from one page to another page in asp.net ?
is there any latest technique other than state management techniques in asp.net?
how? thank you!!!!!

Comment: did this answer feet your needs ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5804721/159270

Answer (score 2):

You have several options when passing data from one page to another:

- Use query string
- Use HttpPost
- Use Session State
- Use Public Properties
- Use Control Info

[This sample from the MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-Pass-Data-Between-935838e4) shows all these in action.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please explain what you mean by "other than state management techniques"?

You can use query string as well.

Can you please check [Communication between pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36916/communication-between-pages) for more details.